# Pyplot plots points in middle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why do pyplot plots in middle? I want it to be on the left side.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1 for _ in range(10)]
y = [i for i in range(1,11)]

plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Even if I add `xticks` and `yticks`, it does not work.

Comment: Try setting the xrange to (0.95, 5) and it will work.

Comment: `plt.xlim(0, 50)`?